# Prevent gradle from skipping a task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a bunch of tasks that are run in sequence and some are skipped based on values in a properties file.

Without changing the properties or the original task definition, how can I tell Gradle to **not** skip a task?

I've tried adding

```
myTask.onlyIf { true }
```

but this doesn't seem to override the existing `onlyIf` call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the assignment operator:

```
myTask.onlyIf = { true }
```

This will invoke the method [`setOnlyIf(Closure)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#setOnlyIf-groovy.lang.Closure-) instead of [`onlyIf(Closure)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#onlyIf-groovy.lang.Closure-), which will replace all existing checks instead of addding a new one.

Gradle often provides both a method to add a new parameter and a setter to overwrite previously set parameters.

Please note, that this might not work for execution of up-to-date tasks. This will only affect tasks that will be skipped due to previously set `onlyIf` closures.

Comment: That's it! Was missing the `=`. Thank you!